# Using CSS to force new line after a specific child within a table

Tags: css, html-table

I'm trying to force a line break immediately after a particular child in a table. the selector works, but it is not adding the new line. Any advice on how to get it working correctly?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#t12  tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2):after
{
content: "\A";
  white-space: pre; 
}
#t12  tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)
{
background-color:rgb(255,0,0);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>The text-align Property</h2>
<p>This property sets the horizontal alignment (like left, right, or center) of the content in th or td:</p>

<table id="t12">
  <tr>
    <td>Row1Col1</td>
    <td>Row1Col2</td>
    <td>Row2Col1</td>
    <td>Row2Col2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row3Col1</td>
    <td>Row3Col2</td>
    <td>Row3Col3</td>
    <td>Row3Col4</td>
  </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

So, the text appears like this

```
Row1Col1   Row1Col2
Row2Col1   Row2Col2      
Row3Col1   Row3Col2 Row3Col3  Row3Col4
```

Comment: Are you trying to have a cell with the width of two lines? Or literally just a space between rows?

Comment: I want the $150 and $150 to appear on the next line, Then Joe appears on the next line

Comment: Question updated to show format of what I was wanting...

Comment: If I add content: "AAAA" instead of content: "\A", then the AAAA is displayed in the TD, but it does not seem to accept the escaped character. If I add <br> into the table itself, then it breaks correctly.

Comment: Based on your comment at my answer I deleted it. To be able to figure out if this is at possible without a script, we need to know what _Within the data stream, I just have the row and column number of where new lines must be inserted_ mean, and possibly also see that code piece. Edit your question with that.

Comment: You don't have the same number of cells in each row and no `th[scope="row"]`, only `td`. And want to display a row on 2 rows: I guess this isn't tabular data then? Quite tabular but not 100%

Comment: Yes, the incoming data is 100% tabular, but the output structure isn't. I'll update the sample to explain more clearly. And no, no th rows

Comment: At the moment I'm looking at setting a length on tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) that forces Row2Col1 to go on a new line. Will post when I've finished testing. Not the best approach, but seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you actually want to do. What i figured out is you want a line break after Lois. so you add a line break before Joe.

```
#t12 tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1):before
```

Hope you might get an idea to get your work done.
And if you want 500$ to be just underneath Lois, then you cannot do it in different columns. You either need both in the same col i.e. td tag or in a different row.

Comment: I have updated the question with what I was wanting. I had used the after, but it is not working